# how to select 2 records from a group in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have two tables: 1st is parent table and 2nd is child. I want to select 2 records of all parent id from child table.

how can I select unique 2 records of each parent.

```
example :
parent table
parent_id group_name
1  first
2  second

child table
child_id parent_id name
1        1         'test1'
2        2         'test2'
3        1         'test3'
```

I have already tried with statement but I found only one row from all parent id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WITH cte AS    
(    
   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.parent_Id ORDER BY c.name DESC) AS rn,c.child_id, p.group_name,c.name    
   FROM parent as p join child as c on p.parent_Id=c.parent_id
) 


SELECT *    
FROM cte    
WHERE rn <3
```